# How do I click on the "Tweet Image" button on Tradingview?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, trading, tradingview-api

I am trying to access this website: [Tradingview.com](https://in.tradingview.com/)

I wrote a piece of Python code which uses selenium to do access it. After accessing the website, my goal is to click on the "Tweet Image" button. In order to do so, I need to first find the camera buttons' css path so that I can click on it. I cannot find the css path to the camera button.

Here is how it looks like:
[image: snapshot of "Take a snapshot" dropdown]

This is my existing python code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


# some constants
DRIVER_PATH = 'path_to_chromedriver'
EMAIL = 'my_email_id'
PWD = 'my_password'



class Browser:

  def __init__(self, driver: str, keep_open: bool) -> None:
    self.service = Service(driver)
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", keep_open)
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=self.service, options=chrome_options)


  def open_page(self, url: str):
    self.driver.get(url)
    self.driver.maximize_window()
  
  def close(self):
    time.sleep(5)
    print("shutting down browser")
    self.driver.close()

  def sign_in(self):
    # open the sign in page
    self.open_page("https://www.tradingview.com/#signin")

    # click the email button
    button = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "Email")))
    button.click()

    # enter email, password & click sign in
    self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "id_username").send_keys(EMAIL)
    self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "id_password").send_keys(PWD)
    sign_in_btn = self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".submitButton-LQwxK8Bm.button-D4RPB3ZC.size-large-D4RPB3ZC.color-brand-D4RPB3ZC.variant-primary-D4RPB3ZC.stretch-D4RPB3ZC")
    sign_in_btn.click()

  def click_products_tab(self):
    products_tab = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Products")))
    products_tab.click()

  def click_tweet_image(self):
    tweet_image = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Tweet Image")))
    tweet_image.click()

  def save_chart_img(self):
    ActionChains(self.driver).key_down(Keys.ALT).send_keys('s').perform()
    element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Save image')))
    element.click() 


browser = Browser(DRIVER_PATH, True)

# sign in
browser.sign_in()

# click on "Products" tab
browser.click_products_tab()

# click on "Tweet Image" button
# I'm stuck here
```

I need help finding the css path of that camera button. I have tried right-clicking and inspecting it but everytime I right click, I don't get an option to inspect it.

Comment: Can you please share the HTML code for that from parent node.

Comment: Visit the Tradingview website or click on the link I gave above. Then right click and click on Inspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on the ***camera button*** element within [**TradingView**](https://in.tradingview.com/) website you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[aria-label='Take a snapshot'] > div#header-toolbar-screenshot"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@aria-label='Take a snapshot']/div[@id='header-toolbar-screenshot']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```